# findElement по xpath не делает перебор

Tags: list, selenium, xpath

Нужно тянуть в переменную `lastname` только значение из столбца `Last name`, но я не понимаю, почему перебор не происходит. Данные переменных `ele` и `id` меняются каждую итерацию, а `lastname` всегда одинаковый. Как сделать, чтобы в `lastname` последовательно попадали `dsa21312`, `test222`, `test333`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public List<ContactData> getContactList() {
        List<ContactData> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactData>();
        List<WebElement> elements = wd.findElements(By.name("entry"));
        for (WebElement element : elements) {
            String ele = element.getText();
            String id = element.findElement(By.tagName("input")).getAttribute("id");
            String lastname = element.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]")).getText();
            ContactData contact = new ContactData(null, null, null, null, null);
            contacts.add(contact);
        }
        return contacts;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

нужно исправить путь xpath на относительный - ".//td[2]"